# How do you POST data from an IOS app to MySQL table using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My group and I have a project we're working on, which involves creating an IOS app from an already existing Android app. The source code was given to us, but it's up to us to create and link the IOS app to everything that was already linked and created on Android. Basically, we have to replicate the Android app on IOS.

As it is, CodeIgniter was the framework used, and we already have the web code written for the connection in PHP. This is the particular part in the code I've been trying to connect to:

```
function registerUser_post() {

        $emailAddress = $this->input->post('emailAddress');
        $mobileNumber = $this->input->post('mobileNumber');

            if(!empty($emailAddress)&&!empty($mobileNumber)){

                    // Set the response and exit
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('studentregister');
                    $this->db->where('studregEmail', $emailAddress);
                    $query = $this->db->get();
                    $user = $query->row();

                   if($user->studregEmail) {
                    $userID = $user->studregId;
                    $this->db->where('studregEmail', $emailAddress);

                    if(empty($user->studregmobileNum)) {
                        $this->db->update('studentregister', array('studregmobileNum' => $mobileNumber));
                        $this->sendEmailtoUser_post($userID);
                    } else {
                        $data = array (
                        'studregEmail' => $emailAddress,   
                        'studregmobileNum' => $mobileNumber,
                        'studregId' => $userID,
                            );

                        $this->response([
                            'status' => 'Connected',
                            'message' => 'Account already exists',  
                            'data' => $data     
                            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

                    }
                    $data = array (
                        'studregEmail' => $emailAddress,   
                        'studregmobileNum' => $mobileNumber,
                        'studregId' => $userID,
                            );

                            $this->response([
                            'status' => 'Connected',
                            'message' => 'User login successful.',
                            'data'=> $data          
                            ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                } else {

                        $this->response([
                            'status' => 'Connected',
                            'message' => 'You have entered Wrong Email/Password. Please try again.',
                            'data' => 'null'
                            //return api key
                        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                    }
            } else {

                    $this->response([
                        'status' => 'Connected',
                        'message' => 'You have not entered an Email/Password. Please try again.'
                        //return api key
                    ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
                }
        }
```

I've been trying to connect using XCode Playground first, before I attempt to put it in our app, and this was the code I've tried using:

```
import UIKit

let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://thomasianjourney.website/register/registerUser")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("Powered by Swift!", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Powered-By")

let json = [
    "studregEmail": "insertemailhere",
    "studregmobileNum": "insertnumberhere"
]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])

let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in
    if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(dataString)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

However, I can't seem to insert the data I place into our database. I keep ending up with the error: *{"status":"Connected","message":"You have not entered an Email/Password. Please try again."}*

I'm not entirely sure what I should be looking into in particular, or if I'm on the right path with making this work, but any help would be greatly appreciated. There's a chance I'm also doing this the wrong way, so please let me know if I am; I would love to be able to correct what I'm doing and finally get everything connected, so I can move on to the next part of the app. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe you should replace `studregEmail` with `emailAddress` and `studregmobileNum` with `mobileNumber`, or vice versa, the keys should be the same on both sides. The server side code is looking for the value for key `emailAddress`, but that's empty, that's why it is not passing your first `if` statement and returning you the empty field error.

Comment: This worked, oh my gosh! Thank you so much! I appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Savca Marin had suggested above, I changed both studregEmail and studregmobileNum to emailAddress and mobileNumber. The code I placed above still refuses to execute, but I did manage to find one that works on an actual XCode Project (rather than in Playground). If anyone needs any basis for this in the future, I'm leaving the source code below:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://thomasianjourney.website/register/registerUser") // locahost MAMP - change to point to your database server

    var request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            var dataString = ""

    // the POST string has entries separated by &

            dataString = dataString + "&emailAddress=\(emailAddress.text!)" // add items as name and value
            dataString = dataString + "&mobileNumber=\(mobileNum.text!)"

    // convert the post string to utf8 format

            let dataD = dataString.data(using: .utf8) // convert to utf8 string

            do
            {

    // the upload task, uploadJob, is defined here

                let uploadJob = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: dataD)
                {
                    data, response, error in

                    if error != nil {

    // display an alert if there is an error inside the DispatchQueue.main.async

                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Upload Didn't Work?", message: "Looks like the connection to the server didn't work.  Do you have Internet access?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if let unwrappedData = data {

                            let returnedData = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) // Response from web server hosting the database

                            if returnedData == "1" // insert into database worked
                            {

    // display an alert if no error and database insert worked (return = 1) inside the DispatchQueue.main.async

                                DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {
                                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Upload OK?", message: "Looks like the upload and insert into the database worked.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
    // display an alert if an error and database insert didn't worked (return != 1) inside the DispatchQueue.main.async

                                DispatchQueue.main.async
                                {

                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Upload Didn't Work", message: "Looks like the insert into the database did not work.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                uploadJob.resume()
```

The error messages/alerts are still currently a work in progress, but the general code itself works.